# Apple Fitness -> Map not always shown

Tags: ios, healthkit, hkhealthstore

In my app the user can record activities and I also store them in Apple-Health.

For each `HKWorkout` that I create I also save a `HKWorkoutRoute` of the path the user took.

The workouts are properly visible in the Fitness app with data like duration, distance, ... Fine. But the route (the MapView with the track) is not always displayed in the **Fitness** App.  Sometime it is, sometimes it's not. If I query the same `HKWorkout` object for its' route in my code, it finds it, but it will just not display it in the Fitness App.

Now I got a user-complaint why that is now properly shown. And I don't really know where to start digging. So any hint is greatly appreciated!

Also... is there a way to check the data in the Health app? I couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: I have the same problem.. Did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But fun fact, I just got an other user-complaint today about it. If you figure out what might be the problem, I'd be super happy to know.

Comment: For me it was the case that I didn't set https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates so it only saved locations when user looks at the screen

Comment: Ok... I have that set and I have complete tracks. But some are just displayed in the Health app but not the Fitness App. I noticed that when looking at the data in the Health app, that instead of one continuous line, parts of my line are just dotted and not connected there. Not sure why... Maybe having something todo with speed not sure...

Comment: What settings do you have for GPS ? It works quite ok for me with the settings:        locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locManager.activityType = .fitness
        locManager.distanceFilter = 1 . Dotted line is because you have missing gps locations

Comment: @RomanBarzyczak i still sometimes have that problem. Did you manage to get it to work all the time?